# match nested tags and extract only text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from a webpage and save it as csv that will look something like this...

```
Octodata | By Rainer Rillke (source available)
Books Browsable and Borrowable | By Green Cardamom
Wikidata Query Service Tutorial | By WMDE-leszek
```

I tried to extract h3 and h5 tags. But since the count does not match, I will not get the correct results.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://hay.toolforge.org/directory/"
get_url = requests.get(url)
get_text = get_url.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_text, "html.parser")

name = soup.find_all('h3')
author = soup.find_all('h5')
```

How do I match inner h5 tag with outer h3?

Comment: what exactly you want to find can you provide some desired output

Comment: The name of the tool and author's name. expected output is mentioned in the question.

Comment: check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer


def my_filter(item):
    try:
        title = item.select_one('a[href*=author]').get_text(strip=True)
    except AttributeError:
        title = 'N/A'
    try:
        tags = ", ".join(list(item.select_one(
            '.tools-keywords').stripped_strings))
    except AttributeError:
        tags = 'N/A'
    return title, tags


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        wr = writer(f)
        wr.writerow(['Title', 'Author', 'Tags'])
        wr.writerows([(x.h3.a.get_text(strip=True), *my_filter(x)) for x in soup.select('.tools-item')])


main('https://hay.toolforge.org/directory/')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I do not see the tags in the output.

Comment: @shantanuo what do you mean by tags here?

Comment: The text in white background like wikidata, dumps, torrent etc.

Comment: Your script returns 140 tools for author "Magnus Manske" @baduker returns 122 for the same author. I am not sure why the count is different but your count is correct.

Comment: @shantanuo it had to do with an incorrect zipping but it's fixed now and both my and Ahmed's answer return 142 for Magnus.

Comment: Why are you giving so much importance to votes? The results and learning is more important than the other people's perspective.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```py
import csv
import itertools

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://hay.toolforge.org/directory/").text
tools = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")


def extractor(css: str, strip: bool = False, only_select: bool = False) -> list:
    if strip:
        return [i.getText(strip=True) for i in tools.select(css)]

    if only_select:
        return tools.select(css)

    return [i.getText() for i in tools.select(css)]


tools_names = extractor(".tools-item h3", strip=True)
authors = [
    a.replace("By", "").replace("(source available)", "") for a
    in extractor(".tools-item h5", strip=True)
]

tags = [
    ", ".join(a.getText(strip=True) for a in tag.select("a")) for tag
    in extractor(".tools-item p", only_select=True)
]

result = [
    [*items] for items in
    itertools.zip_longest(tools_names, authors, tags, fillvalue="N/A")
]

with open("data.csv", "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter="|")
    writer.writerows(result)
```

Output: a `.csv` file separated by `|`

[image]

Comment: Yes. This is correct. Can you suggest how to remove "By" in second column?

Comment: I added  extractor(".tools-item p") because I wanted the tags as well. It works but removes spaces.

Comment: I do not see the tags in the output.

Comment: @shantanuo Oh, I missed that comment about tags. Let me update once again.

Comment: @shantanuo, check now.

Comment: Your count does not match with the actual for a lot of authors. For e.g. Legoktm 24 (actual is 30)

Comment: @shantanuo it does match. Run the code from the answer again and see for yourself.

Comment: I checked again and found several discrepancies in your results. For e.g. the tool "Data about GrowthExperiments new editor tasks" is not linked to the correct author Roan Kattouw (WMF). Maybe I am confused. Let someone else check and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

```py
result = {}
for i in range(len(name)):
    result[name[i].text] = author[i].text
```

The dict `result` will give you the matches. (The length of `name` and `author` should be the same.)